# Invalidating NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have 4 `NSTimers` objects in my app , that make requests to a rest URL every few seconds.

On clicking of a particular `button` I want to stop the timer so that it stops polling and on click of another `button` I want to resume polling.

I have tried `invalidate` for all timers but does not work.

NOTE: All timers are in different class and I'm trying to invalidate the timers in another class
Any help will be appreciated , thank you.

```
class NotificationViewController:UIViewController {
    var timer:NSTimer?
    getEvents(){
    if((timer == nil)) {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(20.0, target: self, selector: Selector("getEvents"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
  }
}
```

In another class I'm doing this on click of a button

```
class Menu:UIViewController {

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        self.notify.timer?.invalidate()
        self.notify.timer = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the code that you have try.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: `self.notify` object is the same one that you have used to initialize the `NSTimer`?

Comment: No self.notify is another class NotificationViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a separate `NotificationTimer` class and used its shared object all over the project like this way.

```
class NotificationTimer: NSObject {

    var timer1: NSTimer?
    var timer2: NSTimer?
    var timer3: NSTimer?
    var timer4: NSTimer?

    static let sharedManager = NotificationTimer()

    func getEvents(){
        print("Fired")
        if (timer1 == nil){
            timer1 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(20.0, target: self, selector: Selector("methodYouWantToCall"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }    
}
```

Now call this `timer1` object inside any `ViewController` like this way.

```
let notificationTimer = NotificationTimer.sharedManager
notificationTimer.timer1?.invalidate()
```

Or call that method like this way

```
NotificationTimer.sharedManager().getEvents()
```

Comment: The timer fires only once. It does not repeat after 20 seconds

Comment: Have you changed the selector? because getEvents is the same one that initalizing the timer.

Comment: No I havent changed the selector, It is the same . The method is called only once , does not execute again after 20 seconds

Comment: I have add print statement inside method check that it is printing or not after every 20 sec.

Comment: My bad. I had created another class for Timer which was not firing. This works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are losing the original reference to the timers. *One possible [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil) solution*, is to keep the reference across the app. You can do that using `struct` 
:

```
struct Timers {
   static var firstTimer = NSTimer()
   static var secondTimer = NSTimer()
   static var thirdTimer = NSTimer()
   static var fourthTimer = NSTimer()
}
```

This way you could access the timer from anywhere in the program:

```
Timers.firstTimer.invalidate()
```

Comment: No the timer still keeps running

Comment: why do you need statics??? why do you need to access the timers from anywhere in the program??? how is that related to release of timers??? it is not the solution! moreover it is antipattern in most cases

Comment: I want to stop the timer from a different ViewController class , So i would require to access it in that ViewController

Answer (score 0):

1. Cancelling the timer:

   if (timer.isValid()) {
      timer.invalidate()
   }

   timer = nil;
2. Just debug you app and check where you are not releasing the timer.
3. Bear in mind, that timer retains it's target, so if you want to release the target, you will need to release the timer as well, or you can write your own timer with week reference to the target.